# Conditional mutate with data from two data frames

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames, where number one contains new values for some of the rows of data in data frame two (data frame two has a lot more data than no. 1).
I have earlier used the following code for overwriting (from data frame 1 to data frame 2) specific column values based on a number in another column:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(Dataset1)){
  sak.i <- Dataset1$column1[i]
  rad.i <- which(Dataset2$column1 == sak.i)
  Dataset2$column2[rad.i] <- Dataset1$column2[i]
  Dataset2$column3[rad.i] <- Dataset1$column3[i]
  ...
  }
```

This works fine. However, now I wanted it to not overwrite but create a new column with this information. I wanted it to insert the new values for that column if rad.i = TRUE, otherwise just use the values already present in the second data frame. So i came up with this:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(Dataset1)){
  sak.i <- Dataset1$column1[i]
  rad.i <- which(Dataset2$column1 == sak.i)
  mutate(new_column_name = ifelse(
    Dataset2$column2[rad.i], Dataset1$column2[i], Dataset2$column2)
         )
  mutate(new_column_name2 = ifelse(
    Dataset2$column3[rad.i], Dataset1$column3[i], Dataset2$column3)
         )
  ...
}
```

When i run this I get the following error:

```
Error in mutate_(.data, .dots = compat_as_lazy_dots(...)) : 
  argument ".data" is missing, with no default
```

I have read a bit about the error, but cannot seem to isolate the problem.

Note: I want this to work for around 10 columns. Is there any easier way to do this? Do I have to do the mutate command for every column?

Example:

```
col11 <- as.character(4:7)
col21 <- c(0.03, 0.06, 1, 2)
col12 <- as.character(1:7)
col22 <- c(67,23,0.03,1,2,10,16)

dataframe1 <- cbind(col11, col21)
dataframe2 <- cbind(col12, col22)

Data frame 1:
col1 col2
4    0.03
5    0.06
6    1
7    2

Data frame 2:
col1  col2
1     67
2     23
3     0.03
4     1
5     2
6     10
7     16

Expected output:
col1  col2  col3
1     67    67
2     23    23
3     0.03  0.03
4     1     0.03
5     2     0.06
6     10    1
7     16    2
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output

Comment: `mutate` needs to know the name of the dataframe as its first argument - see `?mutate`

Comment: Mutate from the dlpyr package works the following way: data.frame %>% mutate(). You have to specify the dataframe first which you one to mutate.

Comment: A small example added. I added the Dataframe %>% in front now, and the error is replaced by another one:
"Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `col3` must be length 4924 (the number of rows) or one, not 0"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in two steps. First merge on `col1` and then replace `NA`, i.e.

```
final_d <- merge(d1, d2, by = 'col1', all = TRUE)
final_d$col2.x[is.na(final_d$col2.x)] <- final_d$col2.y[is.na(final_d$col2.x)]
```

which gives,

> ```
>  col1 col2.x col2.y
> 1    1  67.00  67.00
> 2    2  23.00  23.00
> 3    3   0.03   0.03
> 4    4   0.03   1.00
> 5    5   0.06   2.00
> 6    6   1.00  10.00
> 7    7   2.00  16.00
> ```

Since you mention `mutate`, the `dplyr` version of the above would be,

```
d1 %>% 
 full_join(d2, by = 'col1') %>% 
 mutate(col2.x = replace(col2.x, is.na(col2.x), col2.y[is.na(col2.x)])) %>% 
 arrange(col1)
```

**DATA**

```
dput(d1)
structure(list(col1 = 4:7, col2 = c(0.03, 0.06, 1, 2)), .Names = c("col1", 
"col2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

dput(d2)
structure(list(col1 = 1:7, col2 = c(67, 23, 0.03, 1, 2, 10, 16
)), .Names = c("col1", "col2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: Does this create two new columns in the dataframe? I tried the dplyr variant on my data but i only get the error "object not found" for col2.y. 

I realized this can be done in two steps, where i first copy all the information in the columns in question to new columns, then overwrite for each specific observation in the new columns with the data from the other dataframe.

Comment: I misunderstood what you meant. I didn't realize that the full_join command created columns named col.x and col.y! I would guess that the combined values are stored in col.x? Since col.y only contain the new values, and NA for the rest